# Parsing Google Places for all locations in US

Tags: api

I want to call Google Places api to retrieve some filtered places. Does anyone know how I can retrieve all locations in US with coordination and radius? Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all the locations that you need and then use [google geocoding api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert them to coordinates.